# C# сложный массив

Tags: c#

Мне нужно создать динамический массив примерно подобного вида `[8, '/', [[10, '-', 6], '*', 5]]`. Как это сделать? Можно ли это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Динамический массив, это List и в нем вы можете хранить все что угодно, если определите его хранимый тип как Object. Но насколько я понял это зачатки калькулятора, обычно его реализация выглядит иначе `["8", "/", "(", "(", "10", "-", "6", ")", "*", "5", ")"]`.

Comment: @AlexKrass, у меня калькулятор вообще из двух массивов состоял, жаль что скобки не поддерживал

Answer (score 1):

Такой массив называется зубчатым.

```
object[][] array = {new object[]{8}, new object[]{'/'}, new object[]{{10, '-', 6}, '*', 5}};
```

Можно так:

```
object obj = {new object[]{8}, new object[]{'/'}, new object[]{{10, '-', 6}, '*', 5}};
```

В `object` все можно поместить.

Comment: Может использование dynamic будет лучше?

Comment: Сложно сказать, dynamic почти не встречался.